# Remove element from named values in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following function, which is called when a google forms is submitted. I'm trying to concatenate all answers into a single array that's gonna be used latter:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
var respostas = e.namedValues;

for(item in respostas){
    rp = rp.concat(respostas[item]);
  }
}
```

But I would like to drop the timestamp that comes together with the answers. I can access it with `respostas['Timestamp']`, but I can't find a way to drop or ignore it. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the name of the property before concatenate it with the rest.
If the key `item` equals `Timestamp` (the undesired property) just skip the current loop.

```
for(item in respostas) {
    if (item === 'Timestamp') {
       continue;
    }

    rp = rp.concat(respostas[item]);
}
```

EDIT: Based on comments, OP attests that `item` in the for..in loop is a integer, but, unless his/her code differs radically from the docs, the variable should hold strings, not numbers.

```js
var respostas = {
  'First Name': ['Jane'],
  'Timestamp': ['6/7/2015 20:54:13'],
  'Last Name': ['Doe']
};

for(item in respostas) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `item` is an integer representing position, not the name. And the position of `Timestamp` can change depending on the answers on the forms

Comment: Not according to the docs: `namedValues: An object containing the question names and values from the form submission.`. In your sample `item` is a string key of the `namedValues` object.

Comment: Actually, I had another mistake and that's why it wasn't working. Working as intended now, thanks!

Comment: Does it not return a JSON object containing the key as the name of the question and the value as an answer? [namedValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). So item would be a key:value pair?

Comment: @Fino If that is the case and the downvote is yours, consider withdrawing the downvote. Also, if the answer helped, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var cp = [];
function onSubmitForm(e) {
    var respostas = e.namedValues;
    for (var name in respostas) {
        if (respostas.hasOwnProperty(name) {
            if (name !== 'Timestamp') {
                cp.push(respostash[name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I would suggest. Using concat to add an item is overkill, you can just push it. Also is a good practice when you are looping over object properties to make sure that they are its own properties of that object, not inherited from prototype. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

[e.namedValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) returns a JSON Object with custom keys.

```
var jsonObj = e.namesValues;

/* e.namedValues returns data like this...
{
  "test1": "testval1",
  "test2": "testval2",
  "test3": "testval3",
}
*/
for(item in respostas){
    Logger.log(item); //Key
    Logger.log(respostas[item]); //Value
}
```

This should let you access the key or value on the items in `respostas`.

> The accepted answer is better as it does more to help the user to fix their exact problem, however, I will leave this here for future users in case they want to understand how to access the variables in the object that Google Apps Scripts returns.